# How to remove a blue tint in my SFSafariToolbarItem Image?

Tags: safari-app-extension

I'm building a Safari App Extension on MacOS. However my toolbar item in Safari is blue tinted. And whatever the PDF image I put in my project, the toolbar item does change the image, but the tint stays blue. Is there a way to put the initial gray tint back ?
[image: blue tinted toolbar item on left side of the address bar]

Answer (score -1):

Try to recolor your icon applying a Sepia filter.
That will make your icon appear B&W.